# How to check inf manufacturer

Tags: drivers, installer, inf

I am trying to create a WiX installer that should install USB drivers as well. It installs the application but not drivers. In the log file I have:

> DIFXAPP: INFO:   Installing INF file 'driver.inf' (Plug and Play).
>
> DIFXAPP: INFO:   Looking for Model Section ... DIFXAPP: INFO:   No
> matching devices found in INF "driver.inf" on the Machine.
>
> DIFXAPP:INFO:   No drivers installed. No devices found that match driver(s)
> contained in 'driver.inf'.
>
> DIFXAPP: INFO:   RETURN:
> DriverPackageInstallW  (0xE000020B) DIFXAPP: INFO: The device(s) for
> which the driver is being installed has not been plugged into the
> computer.

I have found ([here](https://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg64133.html)) that it might be a case that Product/Manufacturer can be different from the Inf`s manufacturer. But how can I check the manufacturer of the inf file? It has this section, but I am not sure how to read it:

```
[Manufacturer]
%Ftdi%=FtdiHw,NTamd64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you asking for product/manufacture of usb addon, then simply go to System > Devices Manager > right click on usb: Properties > Details > Device Identification
Should be something similar to PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_6742&SUBSYS_1D821043&REV_00

You should make correct edition of inf to resamble your usb ID

Comment: Well the problem is that I dont have an actual device - only inf. And is that "PCI... " string I should put as a manufacturer for WiX Product?

Comment: I am confused.  Why are you trying to install a device driver for a device that you don't have?

Comment: That application is not for me - I just have to make an installer